# Generate string based on regex with parameters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a basic url generator in JavaScript. I've got a routing table with regex routes. The goal is to generate url's based on the given regex pattern and parameters.

For example I've got the following pattern:

```
var route = /\/([0-9]{4})\/some-constant-string-here\/([a-z-]+)/i
```

With the following parameters:

```
var parameters = [1234, "test-stuff"];
```

How can I apply the parameters to the pattern in order to get this: `/1234/some-constant-string-here/test-stuff`

Bonus: Do I need / can I name the parameters in the expression in order to have named parameters?

Comment: What's wrong with `'/' + [1234, "test-stuff"].join('/')`?

Comment: Why using regex instead of `'/' + parameters.join('/')`?

Comment: Edited the example route. And the other reason behind regex is that the route patterns are used for validation as well.

Comment: Please answer previous comments: Why not `"/" +  ["1234", "test-stuff" ].join("/some-constant-string-here/")`

Comment: Can constant string appear anywhere or always in the middle of 2 regex?

Comment: The constant string can be anywhere multiple times, thats why a simple `join` won't work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers. I found the closest solution to my problem in the `generate` method of the following:

https://github.com/gnoesiboe/route-match/blob/master/lib/utility/pathGenerator.js

It uses the path-to-regexp library to extract regexp from the route:
https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp

- The regexp can be used to validate paths
- The `requiredRouteParams` in the `generate` method contains the required data to build up a path from a route

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use regex in this case. It's better to use [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to customize your `parameters` then join the array to retrieve the expected URL.

```js
var params = [1234, "test-stuff"];
params.splice(1, 0, 'some-constant-string-here');
var url = '/' + params.join('/');
alert(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this one does your job. First validates both parameters then constructs the url.

```
var parameters = [1234, "test-stuff"],
          text = "some-constant-string-here",
           url = "";

/\d{4}/.test(parameters[0])   &&
/[a-z-]+/.test(parameters[1]) &&
(url = "/" + parameters[0] + "/" + text + "/" + parameters[1]);
```